# R-squared function returns negative value

Tags: correlation, nonlinear-regression, r-squared, javascript

The following JavaScript code is supposed to calculate R<sup>2</sup> based on two numerical arrays of equal length- yPred and yTrue. It is based on the formula R<sup>2</sup>=1-RSS/TSS.

```
function rSquared(yPred, yTrue) {
    // Calculate rss
    var rss = yTrue.map(
        (value, index) => Math.pow(value - yPred[index], 2)
    ).reduce((partialSum, value) => partialSum + value);
    // Calculate yMean
    var yTrueMean = yTrue.reduce((partialSum, value) => partialSum + value) / yTrue.length;
    // Calculate tss
    var tss = yTrue.map(
        value => Math.pow(value - yTrueMean, 2)
    ).reduce((partialSum, value) => partialSum + value);
    // Calculate R squared
    var r2 = 1 - (rss/tss);

    return r2;
};
```

My understanding is that R<sup>2</sup> is supposed to always return a value between 0 and 1. However, when I feed the function above the following two arrays, I get a return value of -1.93.

```
yPred = [0.3750440776348114, -0.012287416495382786, -0.6459235548973083, -0.5996115803718567, 0.1389559656381607, 0.15390433371067047, -1.0472080707550049];
yTrue = [0.15616384148597717, 1.0833866596221924, 0.009760240092873573, 0.2537662386894226, -0.6734565496444702, 0.5953746438026428, 0.3025674521923065];
```

Meanwhile, when I enter these two arrays into [this online R<sup>2</sup>-calculator](https://ncalculators.com/statistics/r-squared-calculator.htm), I get 0.97. Notably, this calculator simply squares the Pearson correlation coefficient to get R<sup>2</sup>.

Why is my function returning an invalid value even though my calculations are correct? And how can the difference between the outcomes of these two calculations be explained?

Comment: Either your code is wrong or the data isn't what you think it is.  In this case, it is the fact that the mean difference between `yTrue` and `yPred` is not zero, so your calculation of `rss` is not returning the error variance but the mean squared error, which, of course, can be arbitrarily larger than the variance of `yTrue`.  $R^2$ is not meaningful if the errors are biased.